# Signup in two different wordpress at the same time

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I Have two wordpress website with many users in it. but now i don't want that a user signup in both of them individually. Please can someone help me to connect the same signup form to both wordpress website.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

you have two ways to do that.

**1.** use an ajax call to the second wordpress website and post all data to there by ajax and register user

*note*: you have to enable `Cross Origin resource sharing` on your server.

**2.** use a core wordpress function called `wp_safe_remote_post` or `wp_remote_post`.

here is an example of action to be added

```
add_action('user_register','custom_user_register_new_site',10,1);

function custom_user_register_new_site($user_id){
    $url = 'http://www.example.com/wp-login.php?action=register';
    wp_safe_remote_post($url, ['body'=>$_POST]); // also you can create your own body data as array to be sent. I am sending all data.
}
```

please let me know if it works or not. (code not tested on real website.

Comment: I add this in function.php of theme that I use not in the global function.php